# Visual Studio 2013 automatically resets projects loaded-unloaded status

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 to develop a solution including 35 projects. Few of them are normally unloaded for several reasons.

Maybe I am missing something, but sometimes when I load the solution, all projects are loaded and made available, as if the IDE had lost the information about their status.

The solution source is not stored on Visual Studio Team Services.

I moved to VS2013 since a couple of months and never had this behavior with VS2010.
Has it something to do with the VS2013 feature to store the IDE settings in the cloud?
Anybody else had this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly the same issue. But I couldn't find a lot of people mentioning this, so it must be something isolated to some configuration.
Or maybe an add-in ?

Comment: @andycted Thanks for your comment. In case I found a solution or an explanation I will post it here.

Comment: ok, I'm not uploading anything to the cloud I think. But one common trait is that I jumped from VS 2010 too. Out of curiosity I tried with a brand new solution created in VS2013, but no change. 
HOWEVER, in safe mode apparently this problem goes away. We should probably compare installed extensions ?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the solution, in my case at least.

devenv.exe /safemode is a workaround, but I found out that uninstalling Xamarin Studio VS plugin worked for me.

One more bug for Xamarin. I think I filed 100 of them, most of which are still up in the air. The VS plugin is the most buggy piece of code I saw on the net in a long time...

Comment: Thanks Andy for following up. The extensions/plugin consideration could be valid also for me. Now it is at least one month that I don't see any project resets. I will pay attention to my installed extensions now... I remember that I recently (couple of weeks ago) uninstalled one or two but I don't remember their names.

Comment: I submitted the bug on bugzilla and I think it was confirmed. Anyway, once you find out that's the solution, can this be marked as such ?

Comment: Might be helpful to link back to the bugzilla: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=17334

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the MSBuild version... I've had to modify the .csproj file of the project. When opening from VS2013, it opened the solution but the project always went into unloaded state.

=> changed the ToolsVersion property in the .csproj file as follows:

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="12.0">
```

oldValue=4.0 (if using Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012)

newValue=12.0 (for using Visual Studio 2013)

After changing from 4.0 to 12.0 the project opens fine...