# How to understand what warning symbols mean in VS2017 project dependencies

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

Any idea on how to understand what lies behind the warning symbols of the dependencies when hovering over it does not give any info?

[image: Dependencies screenshot of my project in VS2017]

**Those ares the steps I have taken so far**

1. Hovering over it : does not give any indication
2. `Update-Package -reinstall` in the NuGet console : nothing to update.
3. When I build, I only get one warning that seems unrelated:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State :
>   Warning   MSB3088 Could not read state file
>   "obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\AutoscoutLibrary.csprojAssemblyReference.cache".
>   The process cannot access the file
>   "C:\Users\alexa\source\repos\myproject\Library\obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\Library.csprojAssemblyReference.cache'
>   because it is being used by another
>   process.  AutoscoutLibrary    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets    2110`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do Yellow Warning Triangles mean on Dependencies in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833402/what-do-yellow-warning-triangles-mean-on-dependencies-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Hello @RomanMarusyk, no I have seen this post and did not get an answer out of it

Comment: I have updated my question to reflect steps taken from answers of that post

Comment: Do you have the latest .NET COre SDK installed? https://www.microsoft.com/net/download

Comment: Try manually going into your project directory and deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders. Then, rebuild in Visual Studio. You might need to do this for any project dependencies as well. Sometimes things get corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I've just deleted the folders such as `bin` and `obj` as @ChrisPratt said in comments and warning disappeared.

So to avoid this warning you need:

- delete the folders such as `bin` and `obj`
- rebuild your solution