# Yellow triangle in dependencies when referencing other projects from the solution

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Similar questions have been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54185914/net-core-project-dependencies-yellow-triangle), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833402/what-do-yellow-warning-triangles-mean-on-dependencies-in-visual-studio-2017), etc., but they all refer to problems with *external* references. In my solution I want to make a reference from one C# project to another, so the output of `projectB` is available in the output of `projectA` (Copy Local: yes). However, as `ProjectB` is listed in `projectA` dependencies, it's listed with a warning yellow triangle:

[image: example picture]

The first project in the "Projects" branch is a library, but the second project (the would be `ProjectB`) is a .Net console executable from which I don't require anything but the executable itself.

I'm guessing VS2019 is complaining because I'm not exporting anything from the `ProjectB` assembly, so nothing can be imported into `ProjectA`. The same behavior happens if `ProjectB` is a C++ project.

My question is: is there a better way to reference one project from another, so the referenced project is compiled and copied into the other project's output directory? (I mean, without resorting to ugly hacks like making `ProjectB`'s output dir the same as `ProjectA`'s or adding custom steps to `ProjectB`).

Please note that my current configuration *works as intended*, except for the annoying/misleading warning icon in the browser.

This is how `ProjectB` is referenced from `ProjectA.csproj`:

```
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj">
      <Private>true</Private>
    </ProjectReference>
```

**EDIT:** Added clarification about custom step.

Comment: It’s not really necessary to blur out project names.  Pretty sure no private or IP information can be gleamed by not doing so

Comment: @MickyD Since I'm using my real name competition might guess what I'm working on (I work in a very small niche in my country).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the console application as a reference with `Copy Local`=Yes, and setting output path to `ProjectA`'s, you should write a command for post-build event in Visual Studio:

1. Go to `ProjectB`'s properties
2. Choose Build Events tab and find "Post-build event command line" textbox
3. Write a copy command using relative paths and macros

Just as an example:

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(ProjectName).exe" "$(SolutionDir)ProjectA\Debug\bin\$(ProjectName).exe"
```

Update: if you don't want `ProjectB` to be aware of `ProjectA` (I can't think why), then add the steps to `ProjectA`. To make sure `ProjectB` is built before being copied to `ProjectA`'s bin directory, either add a pre-build command to build `ProjectB`, or set correct build order and make sure you always build the entire solution before running `ProjectA` so latest changes in `ProjectB`'s code are compiled and copied over.

Comment: Thank you, but that's no what I need, since I don't want `ProjectB` to be aware of `ProjectA`. I'll make it clearer in the question.

Comment: Then add custom post-build/pre-build event to `ProjectA`. Edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The problem with pre-build/post-build is that the projects may have different output folders because they could have different architectures, release/debug build configurations, etc. I certainly can open a CMD box and copy the files manually even, but I was 1) hoping that the build environment would handle that automatically (given that it does everything I want except for the warning overlay) and 2) hoping for an explanation as for why does the warning overlay shows up in the first place. Notice that my question is "is there a better way to **reference** one project from another?"