# Visual Studio 2019 Project Dependency with Yellow Icon

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I have two brand new C# .NET Standard libraries.  They each have a project reference to an older .NET 3.5 Framework library.  Only one of the two have a yellow icon on the reference.

Everything builds and runs fine but the triangle still exists, why?

Comment: A yellow icon on the reference usually means the actual file used cannot be located. If you click the reference can you see its Path in its properties list? Compare the paths, one without the icon to the one with and see the difference.

Comment: What is strange is that one project is clearly happy, and the other is not, despite them both referencing the same project.  The DLL does exist in that project's bin folder.

Comment: @Zoop Hi friend, any update for this issue? Does it persist, or can the error list window help locate the issue? :)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Apologies, I am thrown around like a ragdoll on many projects! Finally got back to this this morning, opened it up, switched branch, and suddenly, no yellow warning icons.  I haven't gotten the opportunity to change anything, so all I can think of is maybe restarting Visual Studio straightened out some internal caching or something.  It may also explain why it still compiled and ran.  It was very strange that two projects could reference the same third project, but only one of those two projects showed the warning icon.

Comment: If you have any pull at Microsoft, may I recommend a tool tip on broken references?  Or perhaps a right click menu option to drill into any warnings or errors on a dependency?  As you stated in your nice explanation below, it can be very cumbersome to crawl through the huge log.

Comment: @Zoop Sorry for the delay. You can post a feature request by `suggest a feature` option in [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html), but only if it gets enough votes the product team would consider adding this new feature. And most of the time, you can find clear error info in Error List instead of crawl through the huge log in build output window. Hope it helps;)

Comment: While this question has a better answer than [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833402/what-do-yellow-warning-triangles-mean-on-dependencies-in-visual-studio-2017), I believe it is technically a duplicate as it's trying to solve the same problem. Unfortunately, the linked question is older, making this one a duplicate. Either way, thank you for asking it because the answer helped me, so +1 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would hope they have a better way to report reference issues
>   than an unlabeled yellow icon.

Not sure if it's your real question. But you can check the **[Error List window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/error-list-window?view=vs-2019)** to get details about why **yellow icon** displays on the References.

[image]

> Everything builds and runs fine.

For some scenario, the build in VS can succeed although some build warnings occurs. And it will only fail when some build errors exist.

I add reference to `ForTest.dll` in my project, this assembly is missing or not compatible with current project, then it displays **yellow icon** in `References`. Now since in my project, it doesn't call functions from the `ForTest.dll`, so it won't exactly affect my build process. Then the project builds successfully and runs fine.

> I have tried looking at the build log, in detailed mode, for an error
>   message, but cannot find anything **obvious**.

When building a solution with several projects, and set the log in `Detailed mode`, it's easier to `get lost` in the hundreds of build logs. Since the **yellow icon** only displays for one project, you can `right-click the project=>rebuild` to build the project, it makes the message in build log more clear.

Or just use the **Error List window** as I suggest above to check the warnings and errors instead of hundreds of logs during Trouble-shooting.

**In addition:** If you can't find any info in **Error List window**, then maybe the reason why the **yellow icon** occurs is because `VS didn't load the project well`. Please try `right-click the project=> unload and reload the project` in `solution explorer`. If it persists,close all vs instance and delete the `.vs` folder in solution directory, and restart vs.

Comment: Due to other circumstances, I ended up restarting Visual Studio, which seems to have removed the warning, which is effectively the equivalent of unreloading and reloading the project.

Answer (score 3):

According to Microsoft, these yellow warning signs get added for every new reference and then removed once the reference is successfully added (=assumed guilty until proven innocent). If some yellow warning remains in the solution explorer, VS knows only that that reference is missing, but doesn't know why and can therefore not display a warning message in the Error window.

Not being able to find out why there is a warning sign is very annoying. The problem was reported, but Microsoft's standard response is: "This problem seems not to be requested enough to be resolved, but if you like, you can contribute your own solution."

So if you read so far, can you please go to [developercommunity.visualstudio.com: tell me what's wrong with the reference 2](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1006951/tell-me-whats-wrong-with-the-reference-2.html) and vote this issue up, telling MS they should indeed fix this.

After spending hours trying to solve a none existing error, I gave up and closed VS. When I started it again, the problem was gone.

Comment: The close-and-reopen VS approach has worked for me, and it's silly this should even have to be a thing.

Answer (score 2):

These errors also occur when adding a NuGet package that is not compatible with the current .NET (such as .NET Framework app under .NET Standard or .NET Core, or a .NET version such as referencing .NET Framework 4.8 library from an older .NET version).

Check that the package dependency is the same as the project you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

It could also mean that the *third party* assembly you have on your machine is not registered in the gac and hence not being found. For older projects mostly if I have to hand copy over the dlls, I will then register them with this powershell script in the directory they reside in:

```
 gci *.dll | % { gacutil /i $_.Name }
```