# How to know what is the dependency problem when VS2022 "Solution Explorer" window show a "Warning icon" (into a triangle)

Tags: c#, dependencies, icons, warnings, visual-studio-2022

I read and try most solutions without success of: [What do Yellow Warning Triangles mean on Dependencies in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46833402/what-do-yellow-warning-triangles-mean-on-dependencies-in-visual-studio-2017)

I saw a request to Microsoft to fix the problem but without any fix : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/solution-explorer-dependencies-shows-warning-icon/600282

There is no explanation and no tooltip over the warning icon and the dependency itself.

I tried:

- Clean and rebuild solution (also done after each other try below)
- Restart Visual Studio
- Execute: "dotnet restore" at the "Package Manager Console" Window
- Unload / Reload project (right click project in "Solution Explorer")
- Ensure that every projects are built with same "target framework"(.NET 7.0) and "Config" (Debug-x64)
- Updated my solution NuGet packages

The bug appeared on the first build after I added a new Nuget Package.

The problem is still there and I don't know what to do?

Answer (score 0):

2 Nuget packages were incompatible. I had to remove one of the 2 (anyone) to fix the problem.

In my case, it was OpenDnp3 and Dnp3 by StepFunctionIO.